# How to find the nearest integer to a specified integer from a table of integers?

Tags: mysql

How to find the nearest integer upon the provided one?

Say, I have the following integers in the mysql database: 405, 600, 304. The question is how to I select 600 upon providing 550 or select 304 upon providing 300 (ie, so as to find the nearest integer)?

i am talking about INTEGERS, not floats.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please rephrase it to make it clearer what you are arsking for.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a table with a column containing some integers and you want to find the row with the integer closest to your input then use the following query:

To find the integer closest to 300:

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
ORDER BY ABS(column1 - 300)
LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
304
```

Or for input 550:

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
ORDER BY ABS(column1 - 550)
LIMIT 1
```

Result:

```
600
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (column1 INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES
(405),
(600),
(304);
```